# How do you relate "paranoia" to something?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

To cut a short story shorter, I'm not entirely sure how to use the word "paranoia" in relation to a specific subject. That is, if one is paranoid about the government, would they have a paranoia "over" the government, a paranoia "about" the government, a paranoia "concerning" the government, or something else entirely?

Comment: I feel like it would be "paranoid about" not "a paranoia __" to better fit. However, if you have to use paranoia, you could say that "The government is giving them paranoia."

Comment: I don't think you do. I'm not sure that paranoia is supposed to take an object. It's a mental disorder, and the word's usage shares much in common with, say, "schizophrenia".

Answer (score 2):

Here are several ways of doing it:

> 1a He was paranoid about conspiracy theories.
>
> 1b He was paranoid that the IRS would audit him.

Notice that in both sentence, you could substitute *afraid* in place of *paranoid*.

> 2a He had a veritable paranoia about conspiracy theories.
>
> 2b He had a veritable paranoia that the IRS would audit him.

Here you could substitute *fear*.